# Can CPU temperatures below "critical" cause severe permanent damage to my computer?

Tags: hardware-failure, overheating, cpu-temperature

I have a Toshiba Satellite P755-S5215 laptop, from 2012. It's got a 2.2 GHz Intel Mobile i7-2670QM CPU, with a stock board and integrated graphics.

It's a good workhorse, but sometimes it undergoes an emergency poweroff because CPU temperatures exceed what my laptop's physical thermometer considers a  `critical` level of `100° C`. This is usually when I'm playing a resource-intensive game and haven't throttled CPU throughput, or [when systemd wants to be annoying](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254505/why-does-my-users-login-cause-systemd-to-use-up-a-cpu).

On the other hand, if I'm playing a resource-intensive game and I remembered to throttle the CPU's governors, the temperature sits around `87° C`, which is a degree above what the thermometer considers `high`. The computer can run like this, but I wonder what the board and parts are actually capable of.

Most of the snippets of data I've been able to find say `100° C` is typical, but my guess is that's just a ballpark for manufacturers and OEMs to cover their hindsides against a lawsuit.

Could maintaining a CPU temperature tolerably below the `critical` level (but still hot enough to, for example, give any human severe burns) have permanent, destructive effects on my computer's components?

---

I use [`lm_sensors`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/lm_sensors) to read CPU temps.

Comment: If your CPU is reaching 100° C then you have serious problems.  You should clean your laptop out and kill the dust bunnies.

Comment: @Ramhound I've done that, but the issue persists. It's not something that worries me dearly, as it's not all that frequent

Comment: What model CPU?  (cat /proc/cpuinfo)

Comment: Its not clear what your question is then.  100° C indicates a cooling problem, a CPU is design to be at load.

Comment: Are you sure your lm-sensors readings are accurate? They match what your BIOS reports? At idle and under load? Mine will report CPU temps of -3C (that is minus) to +5C at idle, and under load quickly jump up to more "normal" 20, 30, 40+. And is your "thermometer" read of high really anything to be concerned about? That aside, I wouldn't really count on any component to last much beyond the warranty period.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes - the hotter you run the CPU the sooner it will fail - however this may not be meaningful in terms of useful life of the computer.

According to this [link](http://ark.intel.com/products/53469/Intel-Core-i7-2670QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) 100 degrees is the uppermost limit the CPU can handle, so there is almost certainly something wrong.

Comment: It should be stated that.  A CPU could run within its thermal limits 24/7 without a problem and without any side effects. The lifespan only gets reduced when the thermal limits are exceeded.

Comment: It could be said the MTBF would then be higher the small likelyhood that it fails or larger liklyhood that a bit is incorrect , and a series of possibilities with techno names that are discussed about what breaks down. . Not that it "Will Fail" but the stats for that possibility are increased.